# When did Western newspapers stop using the term “Japs” in their publications?

Tags: word-usage, style-manuals, political-correctness, demonyms, racism

There are countless examples of highly accredited publications like the New York Times that used the derogatory term “[Japs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jap)” in their articles instead of “Japan/Japanese” during and after WWII.

When did they stop?

Was this an editorial decision made on an article-by-article basis, or did they (the collective “they”) create a style guide prohibiting its usage?

Comment: Are you seriously expecting that all Anglophone sources suddenly decided at some point in time (all for the same reason) that "Jap" was insulting? Obviously it came to have *very* negative associations as we learned more about Japanese treatment of pows during and following WW2, but *gradually*, we have to put the past behind us. And in the days before Google and Facebook, there was nothing remotely like a "global voice" advising us to change our vocabulary. Personally, if I were Japanese, I'd find this question insulting and/or annoying / distressing.

Comment: I wonder how long would "When did people stop using the word ni**er?" last on ELU? It's reminiscent of "When did you stop beating your wife?"

Comment: The words "Jap" and "Japs" continued to be used colloquially through the end of the 20th century by "parochial" speakers of American English who had lived through the second world war, but for many of those speakers it was not meant as derogatory. For them it was analogous to "Brit". When I was in my late twenties, I bought a second-hand wok from a woman who had been given it as a gift but wasn't into asian cuisine and so she put a for-sale ad in the local free newspaper. She lived with her elderly mother. They were both very cordial to me.The mother asked me "Didya marry a Jap-girl, hon?"

Comment: @TimR: Even back in the 70s and 80s, mainstream British newspapers were perfectly happy to use the term "paki-bashing" when reporting on the activities of "bovver boys". But times change.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and of course in 1971 Private Eye had "A Nasty Nip in the Air" referring to Emperor Hirohito on the [front cover](https://dickwife.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/nipinair.jpg) ("Nip" being comparable to "Jap"  in tone as well as synonymous)

Comment: Using Jap as a short form of Japanese certainly lasted till end of 20th century; using Jap specifically for a person would be viewed as more offensive. In view of the [anti-Japanese sentiment of the 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Japanese_sentiment_in_the_United_States#Since_World_War_II) (related to things like Japanese cars supplanting Detroit) there's likely to have been abuse in the 1980s, but the popular press is very different to august broadsheets like the NY Times. (I think specific questions about newspaper style guides are off-topic but general usage is OK.)

Comment: Jap - History and etymology: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jap

Comment: While I don’t want to interrupt anyone standing in the saddle of their high horse over this question, I believe I [found an explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540535). Shosuke Sasaki, an activist, engaged in a pressure campaign aimed at venerable NY newspapers.  He’s likely the person most responsible for the term’s disuse.

Comment: No, that one asks "was the word once neutral?", and, while this one asks "when did newspapers stop using it?", it is essentially a history question which as far as it concerns the history of the word (within the topical confines of ELU) is answered in the dupe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was the word that is now considered a slur against Japanese people ever considered simply a standard, neutral demonym?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540531/was-the-word-that-is-now-considered-a-slur-against-japanese-people-ever-consider)

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit You should make your comment into an answer. It's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Jap&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the use of the word Jap surged between 1938 and 1950 (around World War II) and after a brief comeback in 1971, it's use diminished by the 1990s. So that answers the when question.

As to why, the obvious reason is because it's offensive:

Wiktionary: [Jap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jap#English) - derogatory, offensive, ethnic slur, US) A Japanese person.

Was it an editorial decision in the papers? How else would it happen?

Comment: Do you mean just like how Brit's an ethnic slur?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not a native English speaker, so I can be easily wrong about these things. But wiktionary lists "Jap" as offensive (see above) and "Brit" as "informal, formerly offensive". So it seems that Jap is still offensive while Brit isn't. See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Brit#English

Comment: Wiktionary is not a reliable source.

Comment: @Mitch Merriam Webster says the same thing:
1) Jap: disparaging + offensive: Japanese person.
2) Brit: a native or subject of Great Britain.
1) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Jap
2) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Briton

Comment: @eltomito MW is a more reliable source than Wiktionary. Either can be correct or incorrect, or somewhere in between and same for completeness (captures things sufficiently), but on average MW is by far more likely to do it right. Since I'm already here to give unsolicited advice on how to improve answers, NGrams is good for real data on frequency of use but needs lots of interpretation to be used for semantics: just because it is less frequent doesn't mean (necessarily) that it is disparaged.

Comment: @eltomito Also, single events (like an editorial or original author) sometimes explains things, but sometimes it is just a social trend (eg no one person said "maybe it's uncool to call Germans 'jerries'").

Comment: @tchrist Brit is an ethnic slur?// Brits' failure to nominate women for artist of the year shows there is 'a long way to go', says Sam Smith...from the UK news website of the year https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2023/01/22/brits-failure-nominate-women-artist-year-shows-long-way-go-says/

Comment: **We Brits treat bands, orchestras, sports teams etc. as if they were plural nouns**. I *presume* Americans wouldn’t say e.g. “The Red Sox is on a winning streak” or “The Supremes was a great group”. (Correct me if I’m wrong?) https://motownjunkies.co.uk/2011/01/19/305/